getting phone number of user in a django app from google with social_core
I am working on a Django app that have Customuser model, and I just save users phone number in the model for some reasons.
This is my model and manager:
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not phone_number:
            raise ValueError('The Phone Number must be set')
        user = self.model(phone_number=phone_number, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone_number, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        return self.create_user(phone_number, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=10, null=True, blank=True)
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=self)


    def add_score(self, score):
        self.score += score
        print(self.score)
        self.save()

    def decrease_score(self, score):
        self.score -= score
        self.save()

    def generate_referral_code(self):
        code_length = 19
        characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        unique_code = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(code_length))
        while ReferralCode.objects.filter(code=unique_code).exists():
            unique_code = ''.join(random.choice(characters) for _ in range(code_length))
        ReferralCode.objects.create(user=self, code=unique_code)

    def get_referral_code(self):
        try:
            return self.referralcode.code
        except ReferralCode.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number

i edit my setting.py file for having a pipleline file like this :
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = config("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = config("GOOGLE_SECRET")
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read', 
]
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'accounts.pipeline.save_profile',  
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)

And in pipeline.py, I expect to get user phone number to save in database, but I get None also in JSON file, I don't see any information about user's phone number, how can I get the mobile phone?
from .models import Profile
import json

def save_profile(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'google-oauth2':
        
        print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
        phone_number = response.get('phoneNumber')
        print(f"this is phone number{phone_number}")
        if phone_number:
            user.phone_number = phone_number
        user.email = response.get('email')
        user.first_name = response.get('given_name')
        user.last_name = response.get('family_name')
        user.save()

        Profile.objects.get_or_create(
            user=user,
            defaults={
                'email': response.get('email'),
                'first_name': response.get('given_name', ''),
                'last_name': response.get('family_name', '')
            }
        )
  


google doesn't automatically include phone numbers in the response. This is because the phone number is classified as sensitive data and requires explicit user permission, often handled separately.
To get the user's phone number using Google OAuth, you need to use a different Google API endpoint or a separate request to retrieve it after the initial OAuth authentication.
here's how you can do it.
....

if backend.name == 'google-oauth2':
    # Print the OAuth2 response
    print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))

    # Access the user's profile using the People API
    access_token = response.get('access_token')
    if access_token:
        people_api_url = "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=phoneNumbers"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}"
        }
        people_response = requests.get(people_api_url, headers=headers)
        people_data = people_response.json()

        # Extract the phone number from the People API response
        phone_number = None
        phone_numbers = people_data.get('phoneNumbers')
        if phone_numbers:
            phone_number = phone_numbers[0].get('value')  # First phone number

        print(f"this is phone number: {phone_number}")

        if phone_number:
            user.phone_number = phone_number

    # Set other profile fields
     ....

